# Selenium Python Unable to send mail one dataframe column as clickable link. It send as per code written "<a href="link"> x </a>"

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium

My code is

```
def get_bug_data():
    blocker_bugs = []
    global table_data
        daily_bugs = {"Bug ID":keys[i].text, "Summary": summary[i].text,"Components": comp[i].text}
        blocker_bugs.append(daily_bugs)
        table_data = pd.DataFrame(blocker_bugs)
        table_data['Bug ID'] = table_data['Bug ID'].apply(lambda x : f'<a href="url/{x}"> {x} </a>')
        HTML(table_data.to_html(render_links = True, index=False,escape=False))
    return table_data
    sender = 'xxx.com'
    receiver = 'xxx.com'
    
    def send_mail(body):
        message = MIMEMultipart('related')
        message['Subject'] = 'Blocker JIRA '
        message['From'] = 'xxx.com'
        message['To'] = 'xxx.com'
        body_content = body
        msgTXT=MIMEText(body_content,'html')
        message.attach(msgTXT)
        msg_body = message.as_string()
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.xxx.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login('xxx.com', 'xxx')
        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg_body)
        server.quit()
    
    data = get_bug_data()
    data
    output = build_table(data,"blue_light")
    send_mail(output)
```

Without any issue, code ran successfully, mail also sent. But the HTML fails to render as Link. It just returns the code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: added my last few lines of codes